# PowerShell script set creation date fails on copy of file

Tags: file, powershell

I have written a simple PowerShell script to help my wife organize some imported iPhone video files by allowing her to manually specify the correct creation date. It seems to work as expected, except that if I make a copy of one of the files, I cannot set the creation date on the copy.

Note: The time of day is negligible in this situation.

```
$movFiles = Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\jg\Desktop\videos" -Filter *.MOV
Foreach ($file in $movFiles) {
    $fileName = $file.Name
    $userDate = Read-Host -Prompt "Date wanted for ${fileName} (format--> 1970-02-13) "
    $newDateObj = Get-Date -Date $userDate
    $item.CreationTime = $newDateObj
}
```

When verifying the results, all files have been correctly modified, except a file that I just made a copy of. Is there a way to force the modification of the creation date (short of changing it before making a copy)? Specifically, what mechanism is getting in the way?

Comment: You should use $file.CreationTime instead $item.CreationTime

Comment: And there it is. Thanks.

Comment: Easy one :) Do you want to re-post it as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As autosvet pointed out in their comment, I simply had a mistake in my variable name. The correction is changing the variable $item to $file. Here is the correct code:

```
$movFiles = Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\jg\Desktop\videos" -Filter *.MOV
Foreach ($file in $movFiles) {
    $fileName = $file.Name
    $userDate = Read-Host -Prompt "Date wanted for ${fileName} (format--> 1970-02-13) "
    $newDateObj = Get-Date -Date $userDate
    $file.CreationTime = $newDateObj
}
```

Thanks again autosvet.